# Azure Powershell - AzureAdUser V AzAdUser

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the free developer E5 subscription and have setup a tenancy, created users etc. I have tried creating a second directory that I am planning to use to test the Azure AD Connect tool on a local server. I can switch between the tenants on the Azure Portal with the "Switch tenant" button however can't seem to figure it out with the Powershell cmdlets.

Connect-AzureAD

Set-AzContext -TenantId "My new tenant/directory"

Following these two commands is where the confusion starts. The first commands lists the users from the first directory and the second command shows the users from the directory I have switched too.

Get-AzureAdUser (Shows the first directory, not the one switched too)

Get-AzAdUser (Shows the users of the directory switched too)

Not sure if there is something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because those are commands from 2 different modules:

First one are from AzureAD which is a module designed for tasks within AzureAD

Ths second one are from Az With is designed to handle most, if not all of Azure's resources. The AD functionality is mostly for the module to handle lookups of azure ad objects when checking rbac and assigning access, and not really created to manage AzureAD in any meaningful way (even tho you can do some tasks).

For your task you can use the az module easliy if you just want to look up the users, but if you need to actually administer azure ad i suggest you go for azuread.
To connect to a specified tenant with azuread use `connect-azuread -tenantId 'tenant id'`. I also think it support that you use domain name aswell